# Serializing Map<Date, String> with Jackson

Tags: generics, serialization, jackson, type-erasure

I want to serialize a Map with Jackson.
The Date should be serialized as a timestamp, like all my other dates.

The following code renders the keys in the form "Tue Mar 11 00:00:00 CET 1952" (which is Date.toString()) instead of the timestamp.

```
Map<Date, String> myMap = new HashMap<Date, String>();
...
ObjectMapper.writeValue(myMap)
```

I assume this is because of type erasure and jackson doesn't know at runtime that the key is a Date. But I didn't find a way to pass a TypeReference to any writeValue method.

Is there a simple way to achieve my desired behaviour or are all keys always rendered as Strings by jackson?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: JSON maps are just JSON objects with element name/value pairs.  A JSON element name must be a string.  So, Jackson is generating a string from what it was provided.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The default map key serializer is `StdKeySerializer`, and it simply does this.

```
String keyStr = (value.getClass() == String.class) ? ((String) value) : value.toString();
jgen.writeFieldName(keyStr);
```

You could make use of [the SimpleModule feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html), and specify a custom key serializer, using the `addKeySerializer` method.

---

And here's how that could be done.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.MapType;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory;

public class CustomKeySerializerDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Map<Date, String> myMap = new HashMap<Date, String>();
    myMap.put(new Date(), "now");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    myMap.put(new Date(), "later");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap));
    // {"Mon Jul 04 11:38:36 MST 2011":"now","Mon Jul 04 11:38:36 MST 2011":"later"}

    SimpleModule module =  
      new SimpleModule("MyMapKeySerializerModule",  
          new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
    module.addKeySerializer(Date.class, new DateAsTimestampSerializer());

    MapType myMapType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class, Date.class, String.class);

    ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().withModule(module).typedWriter(myMapType);
    System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(myMap));
    // {"1309806289240":"later","1309806289140":"now"}
  }
}

class DateAsTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    jgen.writeFieldName(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
  }
}
```

---

Update for the latest Jackson (2.0.4):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

public class CustomKeySerializerDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Map<Date, String> myMap = new HashMap<Date, String>();
    myMap.put(new Date(), "now");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    myMap.put(new Date(), "later");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap));
    // {"2012-07-13T21:14:09.499+0000":"now","2012-07-13T21:14:09.599+0000":"later"}

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addKeySerializer(Date.class, new DateAsTimestampSerializer());

    MapType myMapType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class, Date.class, String.class);

    ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(module).writerWithType(myMapType);
    System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(myMap));
    // {"1342214049499":"now","1342214049599":"later"}
  }
}

class DateAsTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    jgen.writeFieldName(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought about something like this.
Anyways it would be overkill for my problem, so I just restructured my data a little.

Comment: I find that addKeySerializer() doesn't seem to do what I expect.  I am serializing an instance of `Map<Foo, Foo>` and Jackson fails to use my Foo key serializer.

Comment: Nevermind, I hadn't realized that I can't use the same FooSerializer for key and value; key serializers must jgen.writeFieldName().

Comment: And nevermind my nevermind... apparently jackson only respects key serializers when you have a class that extends the generic, like `class MyMap extends Map<Foo, Bar>` or the Map is a field in another class.  I understand why these situations are different (the metadata evades erasure) but I don't understand why Jackson isn't just looking at the runtime type of the key object.

Comment: Would this approach work with serializing a Map<Object, Object>?

Answer (score 5):

As usual, Bruce's answer is right on the spot.

One additional thought is that since there is a global setting for serializing `Date` values as *timestamps*:

```
SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS
```

Maybe that should apply here as well. And/or at least use standard [**ISO-8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for text. The main practical issue there is that of *backwards compatibility*; however, I doubt that current use of plain `toString()` is very useful as it is neither efficient nor convenient (to read back the value).

So if you want, you might want to file a feature request; this sounds like sub-optimal handling of Map keys by Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jackson 2.0 (maybe 1.9, too), `WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS` can be used to change this particular behavior.

Usage example for `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
```

and for `ObjectWriter`:

```
ObjectWriter w = mapper.with(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```