# How to use java object as a key In JSON?

Tags: java

Hi I have a Java Class like,

```
// code
class A{
  private int i;
  private String j;
// getters/setters
}
```

I want to use this object as a map key in my json, how i can do this?
e.g : i want something like - {javaObject:value}

Comment: Not possible: all JSON keys are strings. If you can make a bijective mapping between your class and strings, you might be able to do it that way (use the string representation of your object as key)

Comment: And the `value` in the `{javaObject:value}` is what exactly?

Comment: Hi Adrian,
Let say i have a hash map like:-
Map<A,int> map=new HashMap();
and i want it's JSON string.

Comment: this can be achieved using as key a complex json type... but... it is absolutely necessary?

Comment: yup it is, can you give me the format accoring to given object of A as JSON key i.e {new A():value}

Comment: What exactly is the output that you want when using class A as a key?

Answer (score 0):

In that case when you want to convert object to json, use this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html). Gson can be used to do that.

Comment: It's not working as it uses the objects tostring, also below link says that it is not possible:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628698/can-we-make-object-as-key-in-map-when-using-json

Answer (score 0):

You can bind key with any object and map the key-name with json key, use Jackson library to achieve this  -

1.You can create data binding POJO like below -

```
  class A{

  @JsonProperty("key_name")
  private int i;
  @JsonProperty("key_name")
  private String j;
 // getters/setters

}
```

2.If you want Object A to be used as a key, then create a pojo like below -

```
 class JsonData{
 @JsonProperty("key_name")
 private A object;
 //getter //setter
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've find the correct answer, actually for complex object as a map key in JSON we have to use:-

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
Gson mapper = gsonBuilder.create();
//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.toJson(myobject); //myobject=any object of class A
```