# How to convert Map<String,String> to custom JSON format?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to convert `Map<String,String>` to Custom Json output e.g:
My Map have data like

```
--------
ID |Desc
--------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
```

My Json should out put above map with custom keys i.e. ID & Desc:

```
[{id:1,desc,A},{id:2,desc,B},{id:3,desc,C}]
```

Earlier I have used List to convert to Json using object classes:

```
List<CustomObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonText = mapper.writeValueAsString(myList);
```

so this converts to what ever fields i have in CustomObject Class.
But as Map just have key/values and no fieldnames, so i need to know how i can set them.

Comment: Write some code? That would be a good start. If you're looking for a library to do this, that's [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site. If you want us to write some code for you, that is too. You need do some research, try and come up with a solution, and then - if solution doesn't work - come back here with that and ask for help. We expect [**much more**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2071828) effort from you. Much more.

Comment: Updated Question with code being used. where  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId> lib is used

Comment: Now, you can google "Jackson serialize `Map`" and go through the several answers on this site and tutorials on the Internet. **Do some research**.

Comment: Have you google it ? It seems you need a guide. 10s search gave [an external guide](http://websystique.com/java/json/jackson-convert-java-map-to-from-json/)

Comment: yup, looking into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628698/can-we-make-object-as-key-in-map-when-using-json

Answer (score 0):

Optimize and enjoy

```
//*******************************************************************
// NOTE: please read the 'More Info' tab to the right for shortcuts.
//*******************************************************************

import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.*;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class MapToJson
{
 // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("1","A");
   map.put("2","B");
   map.put("3","C");

   final StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("[");    


   map.forEach((k,v)->string.append("{id:"+k+",desc"+v+"},"));


   string.append("]");


   System.out.println(string.toString());

  }


 }
```

Comment: how to do it with ObjectMapper/ Serializers

Comment: I see what you need, but as stated in the comments from your original post, you need to write your own custom code.