# Jackson Serialization

Tags: json, rest, jackson

I would like to know how can we serialize the following using Jackson.

I have the following class:

```
public Class School{

private Map<Teacher,List<Student>> exampleMap;

//Getter and Setter

}
```

Teacher & Student are two other entities.

If I now want to serialize this into JSON using Jackson, how should I proceed?

Comment: you can Create Custom Serializer ,if you dont like the default implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json treats map's key as String and it default implementation simply calls its toString method.

The following post has clear explanantion, this might help you.

[Can we make object as key in map when using JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628698/can-we-make-object-as-key-in-map-when-using-json)