# Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type error when using ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm making a Post request from app number 1 where i have the below

```
        UriComponents uriComponents = builder.uri(uri).path("/api/accounts").build();
        ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Account, Position>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Account, Position>>(){};
        RequestEntity request = RequestEntity
                .post(uriComponents.toUri())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(requestStuff);
        ResponseEntity<Map<Account, Position>> response = restTemplate.exchange(request, responseType);

        return response.getBody();
```

My `Account` object is as below:

```
public class Account {
   private String id;
   private String branch;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Code below is in app number 2 and this is where the post request arrives which then returns the desired map.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/accounts")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<Account, Position>> getAccountPositions(@RequestBody String requestStuff){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fetchAccountPositions.execute(requestStuff));
    }
```

but when i try to make this api call, i get the below error in app number 1:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.package.Account]
```

The Account object in both app1 and app2 are exactly the same.

Please help me understand how i can fix the deserialize issue.

Comment: What is your api response  format ? (json) also have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628698/can-we-make-object-as-key-in-map-when-using-json

Comment: JSON needs the keys to be String, so you need to use account.id as the key of the map. or try this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map#2-mapltobject-stringgt-serialization